# parts of speech in a senctence

Tags: meaning, parts-of-speech

> 1. Verbs in the active voice show the subject **acting**.

> 2. Verbs in the passive voice show something else **acting** on the subject.

1st acting is a gerund?

2nd acting is a participle(present)?

Answer (score 1):

In #1, the part of speech is an adjective. That "*acting*" modifies "**subject**".
In #2, the part of speech is an adjective. That "*acting*" modifies "**something**".

"*Acting*" is a present participle, and it can assume several parts of speech, such as:
[**noun** (aka gerund)]: *Running* a marathon takes me about four hours.
[**adjective**]: *Running* to catch the train, I dropped my new iPhone.
[**verb**]: I was *running* the marathon when I got a text message that the database server had just crashed.

So, "*is that a gerund or present participle?*" does not make sense because a gerund is what to call a present participle when a present participle is functioning as a noun.